# Can I set the focus for the first element in a Blazor modal?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I open a modal in Blazor (Server App) that contains an array of strings.  Everything is working code wise, but I have to click in the first element to set focus (these are serial numbers and are read with a scanner).  After that, as scanning continues the focus moves after each scan. I would like the first element to be focused when the modal opens so scanning can start without having to click in the first element.

Here is the modal setup"

```
<Modal @ref="modalMultipleSerialNumbers" Title="Add/Change Multiple Serial Numbers" UseStaticBackdrop="true" Size="ModalSize.ExtraLarge">
<BodyTemplate>
    @for (var i = 0; i < SD.MaxNumberOfMultiples; i++)
    {
        var count = i; // using i doesn't work.  Has to be stored in a local variable to use bind.'
        <input @bind="@MulipleSerialNumbers[count]" class="col-4 m-1" />
    }
</BodyTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <Button Color="ButtonColor.Secondary" @onclick="OnClearModalClick">Clear list of Serial Numbers</Button>
    <Button Color="ButtonColor.Primary" @onclick="OnSaveModalClick">Save list of Serial Numbers</Button>
</FooterTemplate>
```

I did try:

```
<input @bind="@MulipleSerialNumbers[count]" autofocus="true" class="col-4 m-1" />
```

but it didn't change anything.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to use JavaScript to fix the issue.

The modal was changed as follows:

```
<Modal @ref="modalMultipleSerialNumbers" Title="Add/Change Multiple Serial Numbers" UseStaticBackdrop="true" Size="ModalSize.ExtraLarge">
<BodyTemplate>
    <input id="focusElement" @bind="@MulipleSerialNumbers[0]" class="col-4 m-1" />
    @for (var i = 1; i < SD.MaxNumberOfMultiples; i++)
    {
        var count = i; // using i in the next statement doesn't work.  Has to be stored in a local variable to use bind.
        <input @bind="@MulipleSerialNumbers[count]" class="col-4 m-1" />
    }
</BodyTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <Button Color="ButtonColor.Secondary" @onclick="OnClearModalClick">Clear list of Serial Numbers</Button>
    <Button Color="ButtonColor.Primary" @onclick="OnSaveModalClick">Save list of Serial Numbers</Button>
</FooterTemplate>
```

This allowed me to put an id on the first element.

Then, in the code to show the modal:

```
private async Task OnShowModalClick()
{
    await modalMultipleSerialNumbers?.ShowAsync();
    Thread.Sleep(250); //had to sleep for a quarter second to allow the modal to render.
    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("FocusElement");
}
```

And just to complete:

```
function FocusElement() {
document.getElementById("focusElement").focus();
}
```

Comment: don't use `Thread.Sleep`, find a better way to solve this problem

Comment: @buga Is there another way to pause execution.  It doesn't focus without the sleep.

Comment: you don't need to pause anything, you just need to call focus after the popup was shown

Comment: @buga without the pause, it doesn't focus.

Comment: what does `ShowAsync` do ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some demo code that shows you how to do it in pure C# - it's irrelevant whether the code is inside or outside a modal dialog.

In general you shouldn't use `for` in Razor - `i` will always be set to last value in the loop  when the code actually renders.  You should stick to `foreach` which doesn't have the same issue.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@{
    var first = true;
}
@foreach (var country in countries)
{
    @if (first)
    {
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" @bind=@country.Name @bind:event="oninput" @ref=this.firstElement />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" @bind=@country.Name @bind:event="oninput" />
    }
    first = false;
}

@foreach (var country in countries)
{
    <div class="bg-dark text-white m-1 p-2">@country.Name</div>
}

@code {
    private ElementReference firstElement;
    private IEnumerable<Country> countries = new List<Country>() { new() { Name = "France" }, new() { Name = "Portugal" }, new() { Name = "Spain" } };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // Set focus to the first input element in the modal
            await firstElement.FocusAsync();
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

[image]

Add on to answer the comment:

> Why do I care about `i` after the loop has run?

Try running this code:

```cs
@for (var i = 0; i < countries.Length; i++ )
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Clicked(i)">@countries[i]</button>
}

    <div class="alert alert-info">@countries[_index]</div>

@code {
    private int _index;
    private string[] countries = { "UK", "France" , "Spain"};

    private void Clicked(int index)
    {
        _index = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this but it is not a List of strings.  It is an array of strings.

Comment: You can't "edit" a string in a string array, so you can't assign a string in a string array to an input.  As soon as you fix the value in the loop like this `var x = myCountries[i];`, `x` is a copy not a reference.

Comment: I'm just curious.  Why do I care if i has a value after the loop is finished?

Comment: @SteveCross - see the extra code snippet I've added.  There have been many questions here over the years about it!

Comment: I see where an error could occur. If I'm following this correctly, you have to convolute i with something else.  In my code, I only use i for the loop and don't confuse it by value or reference with anything else, but thanks for the tip.